# How do you programmatically remove a file from eclipse build path?

Tags: java, eclipse

**How would I craft a script to remove a particular file from the build path for a java project in eclipse?**

Hence; not going through the eclipse GUI, right click project, configure build path .. blah blah blah.

Much thanks in advance

Comment: Examine the .classpath file within your Eclipse project. You'll figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to do this at runtime of your code or to have some external process to modify the build path for some other eclipse project. One way to achieve what you want is to programmatically modify the `.classpath` file inside the root of the project. You would then parse the XML for `classpathentry`. A typical `.classpath` might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/someLib.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Just a note:  The `.classpath` file format is considered an internal implementation detail.  You can do it ... but it is not guaranteed to work between releases.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse stores these information in a file in the project directory called `.classpath`.

You could manipulated this file, but I think eclipse will only reload the information on a restart.

Comment: Eclipse will alo detect (and fully process) a changed .classpath file when the file is opened in an editor, or when the user does a  refresh on the file or the project.